# What builder is used for Java Apps made in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

I have read [this](http://technologyconversations.com/2014/06/18/build-tools/) to get some insight about mostly used `Java` builders. I have a slight knowledge about how each of them works, but it is still unclear to me, what builder does `Eclipse` use and how can I define which do I want to use.

I have noticed, `Eclipse` project properties has category for `Ant` and `Maven`, so I guess it can use any of these, but who does the decision which one will be used?

It is confusing to me as I didn't find `pom.xml` in the Java Web App and I haven't defined any dependencies as it is for `Maven` typical either. (Though I was adding libraries to the build path)

Comment: Please consider commenting what is wrong with the question, when giving -1, so I could improve my further questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse, by itself, doesn't use any external tools to build. It has, among other things, it's own compiler (not `javac`) and the Java Development Tools (JDT) includes components that "assemble" applications into the build output location.

Having said that, there are Eclipse plug-ins that support building with Ant, [Maven](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), or [Gradle](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/blob/master/README.md). For Maven and Gradle, since those tools also manage dependencies and impose lifecycle and structural conventions on a project, you have to tell Eclipse that your project is a Maven or Gradle project and then the appropriate plug-in (assuming it's installed) injects itself into Eclipse JDT's process to use the `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` to control the build.

The Ant plug-ins are included with JDT; since Ant is more of a scripting tool and doesn't impose structure or lifecycle like Maven and Gradle, you simply manually invoke Ant when you want to use it.

If you have the Maven or Gradle plug-ins and create a Maven (or Gradle) project in Eclipse, the plug-in configures your Eclipse project settings such that it can contribute to the build path (with dependencies from the pom or build file). It also adds a [Builder](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html) to participate in Eclipse's process by injecting Maven (or Gradle) steps in the right places.

Comment: I didn't know Eclipse has it's own stuff to manage the build. I thought it had to use one of these (above mentioned). It clarifies many things. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What happens when I create a Maven project in Eclipse? As you said I need a plug in to build it with Maven. Hope you could answer that.